# Set password policy for AWS Cognito with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I created a new user pool with AWS Cognito and would like to set the password policy.

```bash
aws cognito-idp create-user-pool \
  --pool-name <Cognito-userpool-name>
```

When I am trying to set the password policy as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/update-user-pool.html)

```bash
aws cognito-idp update-user-pool \
  --user-pool-id <userpool-id> \
  --policies PasswordPolicy={MinimumLength=10,RequireUppercase=true,RequireLowercase=true,RequireNumbers=true,RequireSymbols=true,TemporaryPasswordValidityDays=7}
```

then I am receiving the following error message:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: PasswordPolicy=RequireLowercase=true, PasswordPolicy=RequireNumbers=true, PasswordPolicy=RequireSymbols=true, PasswordPolicy=TemporaryPasswordValidityDays=7, PasswordPolicy=RequireUppercase=true
```

Am I using the `--policies` Parameter wrong? How do I need to set it correctly? I am using `aws-cli/2.15.19`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put the policy within quotes as below:

```
aws cognito-idp update-user-pool \
  --user-pool-id <userpool-id> \
  --policies "PasswordPolicy={MinimumLength=10,RequireUppercase=true,RequireLowercase=true,RequireNumbers=true,RequireSymbols=true,TemporaryPasswordValidityDays=7}"
```